# How to make a smoke collision effect?

Tags: animation

I've made an animation when an object falls onto a ground really hard. It is now missing a smoke effect, how can I do it, so when the object touches the ground, the smoke particles (or dust) appear in the collision?

Comment: Have you tried [looking it up on youtube?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URnzT-eyEkM)

Comment: that version is really old, and it's 2 years ago